# Why use start over call when using batch files?

Tags: windows, batch-file

It appears that I can use either `start` or `call` to execute batch files however am unsure why you would use one over the other. What are the benefits?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`call` runs the given script inside the same interpreter instance, so it can only be used for batch files, but it allows the called script to modify the caller's environment using `set`. In Windows NT, `call` also allows labels to be called as subroutines; e.g. `call :foo`.

On the other hand, `start` uses the ShellExecute() function, so it can be used to open practically everything Windows itself can open, including documents, other files, and even Internet URLs. `start` also has options to open a separate console window, to use different process priorities, and to run a program without waiting for it to finish. However, if you use `start` with a batch file, it will run in a *separate* interpreter, and any modifications to the environment will not be seen from the caller.

Answer (score 3):

```
C:\>start /?
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

C:\>call /?
Calls one batch program from another.
```

Call will not start new window and can be used to call labeled subroutine.